# How to make HingeJoint2D harder to move?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a ragdoll guy with a grappling hook, but when I use the grappling hook, the guy gets pulled so hard that his head gets snapped and ends up underneath the other arm.

My grappling hook is already slow enough as it is so I'm not sure how I can remove the neck snapping. Is there any way I can make the head harder to snap?